# Why outlook asks user name, password and domain?

Tags: windows, domain, outlook, password

After updating computer where exchange server runs, some users on domain now have a problem. They say, outlook keeps asking for user name, password and domain. I make some of them to try their passwords but they say it does not work.

I have been using an email on same exhange server and I have no problem. Until we fix this, I keep recommending people to use web access (it is working). Do you have any idea what may be the cause of this problem?

Administrator of exchange server says he has just installed latest updates on windows pc. Is there a relation for some users that tried to connect exchange server while this installation and reboot runs, a misconfiguration in profile cache or something?

Regards,
Burak

Answer (score 5):

Outlook prompts for credentials when "integrated" authentication to Exchange fails (I'm glossing over this a bit). Typically, this happens in scenarios where the user isn't logged-on to the cleient computer with a user account that is a member of a domain trusted by the Exchange Server computer.

Are the users seeing this behaviour logging-on with domain user accounts from a domain trusted by the Exchange Server computer?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the time is correct on the client PCs and matches the Domain Controller(s).

Answer (score 1):

Are you connecting over HTTP? If so, try disabling that.